# MySQL PHP: Selecting data from one table and inserting into other in a different DB: Performance wise

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have two databases in two different servers: db1, db2. I want to transfer some data from one table to the other: copy from db1.mytable to db2.mytable
Which of the following would be better/faster:

A: Select big number of rows from db1.mytable and then send them in small batches to db2.mytable

B: Loop of ( select small number of rows from db1.mytable and then insert all of them in one batch to db2.mytable )

Example:
A:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 200000;
while(not_all_fetched)
{
    fetch 1000 rows;
    insert these 1000 rows into db2.mytable;
}
```

B:

```
while(more_rows_to_copy)
{
    SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1000;
    fetch all of them;
    insert these 1000 rows into db2.mytable
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with 1 simple `insert into MyTable select * from his table`?

Comment: 3 reasons:
- They are in two different DBs on different servers
- They are huge tables
- Subset of the table will be trasfered

Comment: OK, what is database engine on target table?

Comment: I have both cases: InnoDB and MyISAM for the target tables (I use MyISAM because they are part of a merge table)

Comment: Why not make a simple test case and try out both ways? I Would say use B if you have limited memory on first server and use A if memory is not a problem.

Comment: Oh. Then you should look at both of those links first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html . There are too many variables in your equation to have a definite answer. It's really trial and error way you should take - take an example of 100.000 records and do it both ways. Then compare execution time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David Jashee.
The fact that the datas on different servers just requires you to export them first.

On the first server, export the table/columns using "Select into outfile"
On the server 2 import your data using :

- LOAD DATA INFILE .. INTO TABLE tmptable
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/load-data.html
- INSERT INTO newdestination SELECT field1 FROM tmptable

This will be quick